# How to detect hidden text in PDF using iTextSharper

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

We have a PDF document below where some text is hidden (covered with the white box). Is that possible to use iTextSharp technique to detect if PDF has hidden text or not?

I did attach an image of PDF with hidden text and two ways we extract text from PDF

Thank you all in advance for your help

[image]

Using iTextSharp I can extract text in two ways (two methods, ReadFile and ExtractText)

```
    public string ReadFile(string Filename)
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Filename);

        string pdfText = string.Empty;
        string OCRErrorPages = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.ITextExtractionStrategy its = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();

            String extractText = iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, its);

            extractText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(extractText)));

            if (extractText != "")
            {
                pdfText = pdfText + extractText;
            }
            else
            {
                OCRErrorPages = OCRErrorPages + i + extractText + "<br/>";
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
        if (OCRErrorPages != "")
        {
            return OCRErrorPages + " This page contains no text";
        }
        else
        {
            return pdfText;
        }

    }

    public string ExtractText(string inFileName)
    {
        string line = string.Empty;
        // Create a reader for the given PDF file
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inFileName);

        int totalLen = 68;
        float charUnit = ((float)totalLen) / (float)reader.NumberOfPages;
        int totalWritten = 0;
        float curUnit = 0;

        for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
        {
            line += ExtractTextFromPDFBytes(reader.GetPageContent(page)) + " ";

            var thing = reader.GetPageContent(page);

            // Write the progress.
            if (charUnit >= 1.0f)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < (int)charUnit; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write("#");
                    totalWritten++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                curUnit += charUnit;
                if (curUnit >= 1.0f)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < (int)curUnit; i++)
                    {
                        Console.Write("#");
                        totalWritten++;
                    }
                    curUnit = 0;
                }

            }
        }

        if (totalWritten < totalLen)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < (totalLen - totalWritten); i++)
            {
                Console.Write("#");
            }
        }
        return line;
    }
```

Comment: Which version of iText are you using?

Comment: the version is 5.3.4.0

Comment: To a certain degree that is possible with reasonable effort. I would advise, though, to update to the newest 5.5.x version as support for vector graphics (like your rectangles most likely) during extraction has been introduced in some 5.3.x version, probably not yet in yours.

Comment: Is there a code sample that could give me a hint?

Comment: To start with, can you share representative PDFs to analyze whether such a *reasonable effort* solution would help?